# Blank page in local installation of moodle 3.3.2

Tags: php, apache, xampp, moodle

I have a problem with moodle 3.3.2 in server Xampp 7.1. I can install moodle but when I want access to moodle I get blank page.
I don´t can load main page of moodle. I deleted moodledata/cache and various directory of moodledata but nothing.

Comment: did you checked this page: https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Debugging

Comment: the page not show nothing, only the conection restart.

Comment: Better say connection restart than blank page.